# Strange Rigify Behavior

Tags: rigging

I've rigged a mesh. I now want to generate the rigify buttons.

Before I try to generate the rigify buttons, everything is in place, however, when generated, everything looks out of order.

[image]

No idea what to do.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have applied Location/ Rotation / Scale before you generate the rig..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides my comment about applying - which you should do - it seems you added a bit of animation to the metarig = which is a no-no. Go into pose mode and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> - to remove all transforms. Back in object mode - generate your Rig and it all works fine.