# What is unexpect behavior in rigify

Tags: rigging, add-on

[image]

I don't know if it's because of rigify, but there was a time when the SSD stopped and Windows couldn't load.
Is this what unpredictable behavior is? If the program turns off, I think it'll be worth using Rigify
If the computer is broken, I think it will be a little difficult to use.

What is an unexpected behavior in rigify?

Comment: Rigify uses python scripts to operate, so if you have script execution disabled it's not going to work correctly!

Comment: @JohnEason do you use Rigify by any chance? It would make you a better person than me to write the answer… I think a single-sentence answer is better than none.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I do use Rigify occasionally but to be honest have never seen that error here, however I've always had auto run scripts enabled in Preferences > Save & Load. I'd also seen the last posting that you link to in your answer and heard elsewhere a long time ago that it could cause problems which is why I commented.

Comment: @JohnEason security problems, you should make sure that blacklisted paths in the settings are the only paths from where you open untrusted .blend files (as Python can do absolutely anything), you probably refer to my explanation [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243271/60486)

Answer (score -2):

> #### [image: AI Icon] Warning, Potential AI generated content⚠️
>
> **This post is suspected to have been generated with the help of an artificial intelligence, chat bot, or other language model tools without proper attribution.**
>
> There is reason to believe this post was not written by a human due to its structure, and grammatical construction, and has been marked by our community.
> Current AI chat bots are a language models, that means they are like a parrot, they can mimic human language well, but they are built to write **seemingly** logical, **seemingly** factual grammatically valid text, rather than actually **be correct**, like a human would.
> The veracity of the following content cannot be ascertained.
> See the [Concerns regarding AI generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396).

In Rigify, “unexpected behaviour” can mean that the rig is not behaving as expected.

It could be due to a variety of reasons such as incorrect weight painting or rigging issues:
**Info Found Here: [Strange Rigify Behavior](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67521/strange-rigify-behavior)**

If you are experiencing unexpected behaviour in Rigify, you can try applying location/rotation/scale before generating the rig.
**Info Found Here: https://github.com/eigen-value/rigify**

You can also check if you have added any animation to the metarig as this is not recommended and can cause issues.
**Info Found Here: https://blenderartists.org/t/rigify-problem/591997**